# TypeError: sequence item 352: expected str instance, NoneType found

Tags: python, string, list

i am trying to perform sentence chunking in my corpus.firstly i loaded my tagged data and then i was trying to perform chunking in that tagged corpus.here is my code.

```
def load_corpus():
    corpus_root = os.path.abspath('../nlp1/dumpfiles')
    mycorpus = nltk.corpus.reader.TaggedCorpusReader(corpus_root,'.*')
    return mycorpus.tagged_sents()

def sents_chunks(tagg_sents, pos_tag_pattern):
    chunk_freq_dict = defaultdict(int)
    chunker = nltk.RegexpParser(pos_tag_pattern)
    for sent in tagg_sents:
        if not all(sent):
          print("NoneType object in \"{}\": {}".format(sent.label(),sent))
          sent = cast_to_tree_function(filter(bool, sent)) 
        for chk in chunker.parse(sent).subtrees():
            if str(chk).startswith('(NP'):
                phrase = chk.__unicode__()[4:-1]
                #print(phrase)
                if '\n' in phrase:
                    phrase = ' '.join(phrase.split())
                    #print(phrase)
                chunk_freq_dict[phrase] += 1
    #print(chunk_freq_dict)
    return chunk_freq_dict
```

i am getting error somewhere in my corpus ,where and why i dont know.does anyone know what is the issue and how can i solve it? this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiwords1.py", line 184, in <module>
    candidates = main(domain_corpus, PATTERN,MIN_FREQ,MIN_CVAL)
  File "multiwords1.py", line 156, in main
    chunks_freqs = sents_chunks(domain_sents, pos_tag_pattern)
  File "multiwords1.py", line 23, in sents_chunks
    for chk in chunker.parse(sent).subtrees():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/regexp.py", line 1208, in parse
    chunk_struct = parser.parse(chunk_struct, trace=trace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/regexp.py", line 1023, in parse
    chunkstr = ChunkString(chunk_struct)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/regexp.py", line 98, in __init__
    self._str = '<' + '><'.join(tags) + '>'
TypeError: sequence item 352: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a [TypeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) execption. It's raised with message item 352 from tags hasn't type (NoneType), еhis means that in the `sent` [(ntlk.tree.Tree class)](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tree.py#L37) has a NoneType object in sequence.

[This line is the reason for the exception](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/chunk/regexp.py#L98), because [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) can take only [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str). You need check check each item in the `sent` [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) to the affiliation of the [str type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str).

You can use [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) built-in function for this, but the result should be cast to [Tree type](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tree.py#L37).

```
filter(bool, sent) # return a iterator with valid items
```

For check which a iterable object has a NoneType item you can do this:

```
if not all(sent):
    print("NoneType object in \"{}\": {}".format(sent.label(), sent))
    sent = cast_to_tree_function(filter(bool, sent))  # update set object to valid items
```

Comment: thank you for replying.but i don't know where to use filter and also there are 500 files in my corpus how can i find where the error is? like which file contain this error?

Comment: [q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758858/typeerror-sequence-item-352-expected-str-instance-nonetype-found?answertab=active#comment82480654_47759650) |>
you can use built-in function [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) for this case. My version of the solution is added to the post.

Comment: i did this but still getting the same error                                                                                                      for sent in tagg_sents:
        if not all(sent):
            print(sent)
            print("NoneType object in \"{}\": {}".format(sent.label(), sent))
            sent = cast_to_tree_function(filter(bool, sent)) 
        for chk in chunker.parse(sent).subtrees():

Comment: i added these lines in the above code but nothing is happening.i am still getting the same error